# Is it appropriate to encourage someone who correctly answers in comments to create an answer while there is a newer answer by someone else?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Usually, in questions I ask, when someone gives the right answer/hint in a comment, I encourage/ask them to post this as an answer, so I can mark the question answered and give the commenter the credit they deserve.

But what if I forget that and one day later someone else puts the exact same thing the commenter answered into an answer: can I still ask the commenter to post his solution as an answer and ignore the "first answer"?

Comment: I would say yes, others would say no. It depends on a lot of factors though, is it a verbatim copy? Does it add extra useful info? Does the user in the comments respond? Were the comment and answer posted within a timeframe short enough that the answer could just be the same answer provided independently?

Comment: You can ask all you want, but don't demand. I sometimes post a short answer/hint in a comment because I don't consider it a constructive use of my time to post an answer, something I would have to spend more time on than a comment. I can have several reasons for that but I'm not going to change my mind about it just because the OP considers it helpful or correct. I am not obliged to spend that extra time.

Comment: I would suggest that you should be accepting an answer because it answers your question.  Who posted it shouldn't really be of concern.

Comment: @HansPassant i'm not sure what you mean. May you elaborate a bit, please?

Answer (score 2):

isn't the consensus posting a community wiki answer when copying someone else comment?

It means that the answer is a collaborative effort.

So if someone else copies a comment and puts it as an answer but not under community wiki, you can custom flag the answer, we'll have a look at it and if the answer looks like an exact copy of the comment, then we'll convert it to community wiki so no ill-gained reputation is earned from that.